# OpenCV iOS integration failure using cocoa pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, opencv

I tried to install `openCV` for `iOS` using `cmake` but that was a tough thing, one answer was posted to install using `cocoa pods`.
 I tried `cocoa pods` as well. After successful integration, it still giving errors where i have imported the header `<#import openCV2/highgui/...>`
.
All the frameworks are imported but still the same..

 If someone has integrated a successful integration using `cococapods`, he should help me...

 Thanks in Advance

Comment: i am facing the same issue. please let me know when you get to the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of OpenCV did you try installing?
If it is the latest version (3.0), and if you are trying to use the conversion functions **MatToUIImage** and **UIImageToMat**, they are located in the **Headers/imgcodecs/ios.h** ( and not highgui).
The camera stack is in the **Headers/videoio/cap_ios.h**
If you are using the previous versions,the conversion functions are in the **Headers/highgui/ios.h**

Comment: hello,, I need to ask if i want to show image over the rectangle that is created at face or other body part, what method is recommended..